# css display problems in FF

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am using the following code:

```
<div id="trialwindow" style="display:none; background-color: #ffffff; position:fixed; z-index:1000; top:40px; left:200px; height: 600px; width: 850px; border:3px solid #000000;">
<iframe src="game/game.html" style="border: 0; width: 100%; height: 600px;"></iframe>
</div>
```

This works fine in Chrome.

But, the layout in the iframe that gets loaded is totally messed up with Firefox(v7.0.1). I see the layout by using a click callback to set the display property as 'block'.

If I do not work with `display` at all, it works fine. But I really need to be able to hide and display the iframe in question here.

This is the code for the display switching mechanism.

```
$('#trial').click(function() {
$('#fadeoutwindow').css('display', 'block');
var trialwindow = $('#trialwindow');

trialwindow.css('display', 'block');
// To stop bubbling
return false;
});

$('#fadeoutwindow').click(function() {
$('#fadeoutwindow').css('display', 'none');
$('#trialwindow').css('display', 'none ');              
});
```

Here, `#fadeoutwindow` is a div which covers all the other contents when the iframe shows up. `#trial` is an anchor tag.

Help?

Thanks!

Comment: The default display value for the div if not explicitly set would be 'block', so if it works without setting display at all maybe there is a problem with the javascript when you click the button. Can we see tge full code?

Comment: Did you try to hide (switch `display` value) the `iframe` itself in addition to the wrapping `div`?

What will happen if you set `display: block`, load the page, then hide the `iframe` and then show it again using your button?

Comment: “I see the layout by using a button which makes the call to set the display property as 'block'.” — Could you post the code for that button as well? It’s a bit difficult to debug your issue without that.

Comment: Added edits. Hope its a little clearer now. Thanks!

Comment: You could simplify your code by using hide() and show() instead of setting the CSS property display to block or none yourself. FYI

Comment: Have you tried just setting the display for the trialwindow div and removing the fadeoutwindow div altogether - again hard to say as I can't see the code for it but maybe it is affecting the layout.

Comment: Tried using hide() and show() and without the fadeoutwindow. Does not work. I noticed similar posts on some older websites but they didn't have answers.

Comment: What does "messed up" mean exactly?  Is it "messed up" while the iframe has no CSS box (i.e. while the ancestor div has `display:none`) or after you toggle the ancestor div's display to `block`?

Comment: Messed up means that the layout is not how it should be. A lot of image divs get overlaid over each other in the top left corner. Any click event puts them almost in the right place... though they are still shifted.

Comment: Hey guys! Got the solution. Was a Firefox quirk really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is that setting `display` to none while loading causes `elem.style.height`, `outerWidth()`, `outerHeight()`, `scrollHeight()` and other such calls to return 0 in Firefox (and not Chrome/Safari). I was using these calls in the javascript to position the elements.

So, for now, I am using a negative `z-index` to hide the iframe instead of a display setting to none.

Answer (score 1):

This example works in Firefox 6.0.2 and 8.0. Try it with your 7.0.1

http://jsfiddle.net/xw5Bv/

```
$('#show-iframe').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#iframe-wrapper').show();
});

$('#hide-iframe').click(function() {
    $('#iframe-wrapper').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything should work fine, setting display property of parent div should not affect inner iframes…

Have you experimented with other browsers (Opera, IE, older versions of FF, …)?

However, if you stated (which I found not very probable by itself, unless FF 7.01 has some strange bug) that "display" caused it, you may play with it - set display only with JS and not CSS, or replace it with visibility and dimension styles… Or move styles (including display) from parent div to iframe itself.

Comment: I know that the default mode is 'block' but setting it as 'none' initially seems to destroy the layout when the display mode is reset. It works perfectly on Chrome. So, I don't really get what's wrong.